# Performance issue of std::move for different length of std::string

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I recently noticed that std::move for std::string in my program is somehow slower than direct copy assignment.

For example,

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>                                                                                                                          
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t len(atoi(argv[1]));
    std::string str, tmp;
    std::vector<std::string> v(1000000);

    for (auto& i : v)
    { 
        i.reserve(len);
        for (size_t j(0); j < len; j++)
            i.push_back('0' + (j % 10));
    } 

    str.reserve(len);

    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> d;
    auto c(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());

    for (size_t i(0); i < v.size(); i++)
    { 
        //str = v[i]; // copy assignment
        str = std::move(v[i]); // move
    } 

    d = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - c;
    std::cout << d.count() << "ms\n";
}
```

And I compiled it by: g++-8 -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp

Here are some test results:

```
short string(10bytes) * 1000000
    -O0:
        copy: ~60ms
        move: ~100ms
    -O3:
        copy: ~8.4ms
        move: ~7.5ms

short string(100bytes) * 1000000
    -O0:
        copy: ~64ms
        move: ~110ms
    -O3:
        copy: ~9.4ms
        move: ~15ms

long string(1000bytes) * 1000000
    -O0:
        copy: ~190ms
        move: ~107ms
    -O3:
        copy: ~107ms
        move: ~16ms
```

There are some points make me confused.

1. Why 10bytes string has the same speed with 100bytes string if no optimization is used?
2. Why copy is faster than move without optimization most of the time?
3. Why O3 makes less speedup for copying 1000bytes string?

********** ***6/23 Update*** **********

Sorry for late respond. And thanks to all replays and comments.

I use a vector whose size is equal to "v" to replace "str", and write all elements of it to a file at the end.

With this change, the results are much more reasonable, and can solve my first and second problem.

small-string-optimization makes copy faster than move in 10bytes string case, and the results of other cases in my original program are affected by copy-ellision.

Here is the much more reasonable results below

```
short string(10bytes) * 1000000
    -O0:
        copy: ~66ms
        move: ~98ms
    -O3:
        copy: ~9ms
        move: ~9ms

short string(100bytes) * 1000000
    -O0:
        copy: ~185ms
        move: ~99ms
    -O3:
        copy: ~73ms
        move: ~7ms

long string(1000bytes) * 1000000
    -O0:
        copy: ~570ms
        move: ~100ms
    -O3:
        copy: ~510ms
        move: ~7ms
```

But in this results, my third question is still remain.

I remember that compiler will use simd to improve copy with O2 or higher optimization, but seems the speed up of copy are not significant in 100bytes and 1000bytes case.

Comment: It's possible that, for the assignment/copy variant, the compiler will realize that only the last assignment matters for the outcome and eliminates the rest, but that it can't do the same analysis for `std::move`.

Comment: `move` would destroy `v`'s content

Comment: This may have something to do with copy elision. The c++ compiler follows the as-if rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule
However, it can break the as-if rule for copying an item. It may be fair to assume the compiler knows that you're doing nothing with the copied object so ignores the copy.

Comment: To be blunt without optimisation why care. With optimisation probably due to small-string-optimization.

Comment: It's not really fair to re-use the same string object as your target. Don't forget it has to do something with what it got last time.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but when you move one string you are effectively deleting the contents of the other. That doesn't happen in the copy case. Why don't you move all string variables and operations in a separate function and measure time outside that function ? You may have different results.

Comment: Yeah, for the move case; the cost of freeing all individual string data allocations is included in the loop being benchmarked; for the copy case, it happens at the end of the function (when `v` is destroyed) and is not measured.